# How to use <sw-entity-single-select> correctly?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I use a `<sw-entity-single-select>` component like this:

```
<sw-entity-single-select
    entity="sales_channel"
    v-model="setting.salesChannels"
    @change="selectSalesChannel"
>
</sw-entity-single-select>
```

`salesChannels` in my entity has this Definition:

```
(new ManyToManyAssociationField('salesChannels', SalesChannelDefinition::class, CustomSettingSalesChannelDefinition::class, 'custom_setting_id', 'sales_channel_id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new CascadeDelete()),
```

When I select a SalesChannel inside `setting.salesChannels` I have the ID of the selected entity. I know that I use a ManyToMany Field here, but only a single select and not a multi select in my component. I want it that way, because most likely I need to enhance it to a multi select in the future.

So this works, I can save the custom entity and the relation to the SalesChannel is set - I do not do this with the repository in JS, but with PHP and a custom controller like this:

```
'salesChannels' => [
    [
        'id' => $setting->getSalesChannels()
    ]
],
```

My issue is now, that when I use the same UI/Component to edit an item, I get the Objects from the Database, but I need the Ids in `v-model` to pre-fill the selected item in the entity-single-select component.

When I do this, the item is pre-filled and selected. However when I want to save my custom entity - and here I do not use the same php logic as above, but the repository pattern in Vue - then it does not work and I get JS errors like this:

`draft.has is not a function` or some failure with `draft.forEach`

When I do not use the ID in `setting.salesChannels` but the Object which comes from the database and save the custom entity, it works. But the item is not pre-filled in the select component.

So the component needs the IDs to pre-fill the item, but the object to save it?

How can I solve this - or where is my mistake? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your component you could have a computed property that slices of the first id of your sales channel collection for providing the value of the entity  select. In the change listener you then create a collection and add the one item selected. You also won't need the server side workaround that way.

```js
const { EntityCollection } = Shopware.Data;

// ...

computed: {
    salesChannelId() {
        if (!this.setting.salesChannels.length) {
            return null;
        }

        return this.setting.salesChannels.first().id;
    }
},
methods: {
    selectSalesChannel(id, item) {
        const collection = new EntityCollection('/sales_channel', 'sales_channel', Shopware.Context.api);

        if (item) {
            collection.add(item);
        }

        this.setting.salesChannels = collection;
    }
}
```

```html
<sw-entity-single-select
    entity="sales_channel"
    :value="salesChannelId"
    @change="selectSalesChannel"
>
</sw-entity-single-select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. This saved my weekend ;-) I wonder why this is the case and why I can't work with the entity in v-model here.

Comment: But I also need a setter, right? I get this one when I want to add a new entry and I select a saleschannel: [Vue warn]: Computed property "selectedLanguageId" was assigned to but it has no setter.

Comment: Interesting is, when I set it up like this `set(salesChannel) {
                this.setting.salesChannels = salesChannel;
            }` the value in salesChannel is the id. However in this.setting.salesChannel I have an array with the whole object. Why is this the case?

Comment: I updated my answer. You should use `:value` instead of `v-model` here, as we can't mutate the computed property. In this case a setter on the computed property isn't favorable because this will just give you the id, where the change listener also passes the entity item you'll need for the collection.

Comment: Thanks. So the value is always the id, and the items that are passed to my apis are always the collections, right? So in my own php logic, it's intended to set the relation as follows than: `'salesChannels' => [
                        [
                            'id' => $setting->getSalesChannels()[0]['id']
                        ]
                    ],`